# How to get a response from a mysqli multi query or how do I get the number of the row sorted in descending order?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I need to run a query with sorting, to get the rating of users, and accordingly show the user his place in the leader-bord.

I found how to execute the query, but I can't figure out how to call it from the code. I get either null or a query error.

```
$stmAt = $mysqli->multi_query("SET @rank=0;
    SELECT RANK FROM
    (
    
    SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS 'RANK', user_id FROM
    (
    
    SELECT score, user_id
    FROM `fishing_contest` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC
    
    ) as t1
    
    ) as t2
    WHERE user_id = ?";");
$stmAt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['id']);
$stmAt->execute();
$data = $stmAt->get_result();
$userContest = $data->fetch_assoc();
```

I have a solution to use a normal query and by assigning a variable and a while loop to output the position, but it is too long. So I would like to know how to use and get a response from queries of this kind?

Comment: You cannot use `multi_query` like that. You actually should never be using `multi_query`. Forget that it even exists for your own sake

Comment: You have a syntax error here `";");`

Comment: Why aren't you using the `RANK()` function in SQL?